# Why am I unable to append ranges in AVERAGEIF function in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to use the conditional average (`AVERAGEIF`) function in excel to average values across multiple pages of the file based on criteria of corresponding data in another column of those pages.

With following formula:
`=AVERAGEIF(('ml5'!$G:$G,'ml6'!G:G,'ml7'!G:G),0,('ml5'!$C:$C,'ml6'!C:C,'ml7'!C:C))`

However, I am getting an error in using the comma delimited appending of the ranges of the 3 different pages (ml5, ml6, ml7).

What is wrong with this syntax and how can I fix it?

Comment: Why are you grouping the ranges like that? I don't know that that is proper syntax.  Are you trying to see if the average value of the three ranges is `0`?  I think you just want `AVERAGEIFS()`: `=AVERAGEIFS('ml5'!$G:$G,"=0",'ml6'!$G:$G,"=0",'ml7'!$G:$G,"=0")` But I'm not quite sure you want this.  You're checking if cells are `0`, then averaging them if so. ...so the results would be `0`, no?  What are you trying to do?

Comment: The 0 is a value in a different column. So, if the value in the "G" column is 0, then include the volume in the "C" column of that row in the average.

Comment: You will need to do 3 sumifs and divide by 3 countifs.

Comment: is there a way to simply do what i did but correct the range grouping syntax?

Comment: No there is not, you can have multiple criteria but not multiple ranges.

Comment: Create the average for each sheet on each sheet, then take the average of those on the master...

Comment: @SolarMike if there are different number of hits on each sheet that would return an incorrect result

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do with `('ml5'!$G:$G,'ml6'!G:G,'ml7'!G:G)` is called the [Union Operator](https://superuser.com/q/447492/67240).  However, that does not work across multiple sheets.

You will need to calculate each sheet individually and average the totals

```
=SUM(SUMIFS('ml5'!G:G,'ml5'!$C:$C,0), 
     SUMIFS('ml6'!G:G,'ml6'!$C:$C,0),
     SUMIFS('ml7'!G:G,'ml5'!$C:$C,0)) /
 SUM(COUNTIFS('ml5'!$C:$C,0),
     COUNTIFS('ml6'!$C:$C,0),
     COUNTIFS('ml5'!$C:$C,0))
```